# How add plots to subplots using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to add plots to subplots using

```
fig, axarr = plt.subplots(2, 2)
plt.sca(axarr[0, 0])
result = desire_salary.pivot_table('city', 'cult', aggfunc='count')
axarr[0, 0] = result.plot(kind='bar', alpha=0.75, rot=0, label="Presence /         Absence of cultural centre")
axarr[0, 0].set_xlabel("Cultural centre")
axarr[0, 0].set_ylabel("Frequency")
axarr[0, 0].set_title('Salary and culture')
axarr[0, 0].plot(result[[0]], color='red')
plt.sca(axarr[0, 1])
axarr[0, 1] = df.plot()
plt.sca(axarr[1, 0])
plt.show()
```

But one added to subplot, but others no.
I get [image: this graphs]
What I do wrong?

Comment: How about replacing `axarr[0, 1] = df.plot()` with `df.plot(ax=axarr[0, 1])`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use pandas (I assume), the surest way to ensure which axes is used is to pass the reference to the axes to the plotting function using the `ax=` parameter

```
fig, axarr = plt.subplots(2, 2)
result = desire_salary.pivot_table('city', 'cult', aggfunc='count')
result.plot(kind='bar', alpha=0.75, rot=0, label="Presence /         Absence of cultural centre", ax=axarr[0, 0])
axarr[0, 0].set_xlabel("Cultural centre")
axarr[0, 0].set_ylabel("Frequency")
axarr[0, 0].set_title('Salary and culture')
axarr[0, 0].plot(result[[0]], color='red')


df.plot(ax=axarr[0, 1])

plt.show()
```

Comment: Why if I chenge `fig, axarr = plt.subplots(2, 2)` to `fig, axarr = plt.subplots(2, 1)`, it returns `    plt.sca(axarr[0, 1])
IndexError: too many indices for array`?

Comment: if you do `fig, axarr = plt.subplots(2, 1)` you only have 2 subplots on 2 rows, 1 column. In that case `subplots`returns a 1 dimension array, so the valid indices are `axarr[0]` and `axarr[1]`

Comment: but if I want 3 plots? 2 at the top and 1 at the bottom?